# Cannot send emails from .NET Web Application using SendGrid

Tags: .net, smtp, sendgrid

I have a .NET Web Application that wants to use SendGrid smtp server to send emails.

Its a simple one page app, which has its code in `Page_Load`. I have imported the references to the SendGrid via Nu-Get and the reference is fine too.
code goes to timeout error after a while when it reaches - `transportSMTP.Deliver(myMessage)`.
can somebody please help?

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports SendGridMail
Imports SendGridMail.Transport

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Creating Email object for SendGrid
        Dim myMessage As SendGrid = SendGrid.GenerateInstance()
        myMessage.AddTo("RAMESHV@timken.com")
        myMessage.From = New MailAddress("myemail@domain.com", "Vikram Avadhaani")
        myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library"
        myMessage.Text = "<p>Show's over Amigo!</p> <br/> It ain't over, 'till its over!"

        'Create Credentials with UserName and Password
        Dim mailCredentials = New NetworkCredential("<user id>", "<password>")

        'Creating an SMTP Transport for sending email
        Dim transportSMTP As SMTP = SMTP.GenerateInstance(mailCredentials)  'SMTP
        Dim transportREST As REST = REST.GetInstance(mailCredentials)       'REST

        'Send the email
        transportSMTP.Deliver(myMessage)
        'transportREST.Deliver(myMessage)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have access to your SMTP server from the web server on which this page is running?  From the web server, you should be able to telnet to the SMTP server on port 25.  If not, check firewall on either server (or between).  Also some resident AV software might require your .NET process to be whitelisted to allow it to communicate on specific ports.

Comment: FWIW your HTML is pretty broken.

Comment: I am running this app locally from my computer and I am trying to use port 25. i also tried to switch port to 587. also tried disabling the AV and trying in a different network than the LAN provided at work. i still get the same error.

Comment: are you referring to the myMessage.Text? it could be just a plain string.....i added some tags to spice it up. 
the real concern is that i am not able to connect to sendGrid smtp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
- Package the cloud (.Azure) project using visual studio (2012 or 2010) on framework 4.0
- login to Windows Azure Portal and upload the package.
for help please refer this - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-create-and-deploy-a-cloud-service/

(silly me, i was just worrying about proxies and stuff when i had the solution right in front of me :P )